# How can i map a child object with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-3

I am not sure if i am over thinking this or not, but i cannot sus this out.

I have a parent object here called Template

```
public Template() 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Scoring SubProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Scoring object which is a child property of Template

```
public enum MyEnum : short 
{
    Basic = 0
}

public Scoring()
{
    public MyEnum Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I have a TemplateModel defined, like so, which i want to convert to

```
public TemplateModel() 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In my AutoMapper Profile, i have set this up like so, to covert Template to TemplateModel.

```
public class TemplateProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        // converters
        this.CreateMap<TemplateType, string>().ConvertUsing(new TemplateTypeConverter());

        // models
        this.CreateMap<Template, TemplateModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Scoring.Type))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Scoring.Text));

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert TemplateType to string
    /// </summary>
    private class TemplateTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<TemplateType, string>
    {
        public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return context.SourceValue.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i convert TemplateModel back into Template?

If i add the following, i get an exception, because dest.Scoring.Type is not a root property.

```
this.CreateMap<TemplateModel, Template>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Scoring.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Type))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Scoring.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Text));
```

Any help much appreciated.  In this case a `Template` must always have a `Scoring` object, but in other cases i have optional properties.  If someone could help me with both that would be great.

Comment: I wouldn't use AM for this. Use it for the simple, straightforward mapping tasks.

Answer (score 6):

```
this.CreateMap<TemplateModel, Template>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SubProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

this.CreateMap<TemplateModel, Scoring>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Type))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you, i was obviously missing the `src => src` part. Works perfectly